# Copy to clipboard in Firefox extension not working

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

I want to write a Firefox extension, with copy to clipboard and execute an external program with selected text parameter.
I have found this link [MDN Using Clipboard](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Using_the_Clipboard) for clipboard copy, but is not working. When I try to execute with cfx run always I get this error message

> (c:\Works\Firefox\addon-sdk-1.17)
>   c:\Works\Firefox\ExternalOpener>cfx run
>
> The following lines from file
>   c:\Works\Firefox\ExternalOpener\lib\main.js:   11: const
>   gClipboardHelper = Components.classes["@mozilla.org/widget/clipboard
>   helper;1"].getService(Components.interfaces.nsIClipboardHelper); use
>   'Components' to access chrome authority. To do so, you need to add a
>   line somewhat like the following:
>
> const {Cc,Ci} = require("chrome");
>
> Then you can use any shortcuts to its properties that you import from
>   the 'chrome' module ('Cc', 'Ci', 'Cm', 'Cr', and 'Cu' for the
>   'classes', 'interfaces', 'manager', 'results', and 'utils' properties,
>   respectively. And `components` for `Components` object itself).

This is my main.js

```
var contextMenu = require("sdk/context-menu");
 var menuItem = contextMenu.Item({
  label: "Open in External",
  context: contextMenu.SelectionContext(),
  contentScript: 'self.on("click", function () {' +
                 '  var text = window.getSelection().toString();' +
                 '  self.postMessage(text);' +
                 '});',
  onMessage: function (selectionText) {
    console.log(selectionText);
    const gClipboardHelper = Components.classes["@mozilla.org/widget/clipboardhelper;1"].getService(Components.interfaces.nsIClipboardHelper);
gClipboardHelper.copyString(selectionText);

  }
});
```

Any idea is welcome, about clipboard copy or external application execution with a parameter...

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

That doc belongs to XUL based addons, while the addon you're writting is an [Addon-SDK](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK) based one.

In order to use `Component.classes` and `Component.interfaces` in your sdk-based addons, you need [Chrome Authority](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/Tutorials/Chrome_Authority).

What that error is telling you is that Components.classes and Components.interfaces are no defined. In order to use the you must first require them:

```
const {Cc, Ci} = require("chrome");
```

And then use them this way:

```
const gClipboardHelper =Cc["@mozilla.org/widget/clipboardhelper;1"].getService(Ci.nsIClipboardHelper);
gClipboardHelper.copyString(selectionText);
```

**Cc** stands for `Component.classes`, and **Ci** for `Components.interfaces`. Please read the doc about Chrome Authority to understand them and the other properties ;)

Comment: console.error: externalopener:
  Message: TypeError: Cc['@mozilla.org/widgetclipboardhelper;1'] is undefined
  Stack:
    menuItem<.onMessage@resource://gre/modules/addons/XPIProvider.jsm -> jar:......

Comment: Sorry, my bad, I was missing an slash in "@mozilla.org/widgetclipboardhelper;1". It must be "@mozilla.org/widget/clipboardhelper;1" Notice the slash between "widget" and "clipboardhelper". I edited my anwser to fix that.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is exactly what you're looking for: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/High-Level_APIs/clipboard

You can use it like this:

```
var clipboard = require("sdk/clipboard");
clipboard.set("Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet");
var contents = clipboard.get();
```